# Rails 4 Postgres Array attribute: how can I ensure that the attribute is an array during validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, validation

I just started experimenting with the native Postgres array type in Rails 4, and I'm running into an issue I can't figure out. I want the app to raise an error if the value for an array attribute is not an array.

Before, when I was using a regular text type for the field, and serializing it with Rails, I was able to make sure the attribute was an array with a custom validation like this:

```
def format_of_admin_email
  regexp = /.+@.+\..+/i
  if admin_emails.present? &&
      (!admin_emails.is_a?(Array) || admin_emails.detect { |a| a.match(regexp).nil? })
    errors[:base] << "admin_emails must be an array of valid email addresses"
  end
end
```

But now that the field is a Postgres array, it seems like Rails automatically converts the string input into an empty array, so the validation never fails. Here's my migration:

```
class AddAdminEmailsToLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :locations, :admin_emails, :text, array: true
  end
end
```

If I create a Location where admin_emails is a string:

```
Location.create!(admin_emails: "this should fail")
```

it doesn't raise a validation error, and it sets admin_emails to an empty array.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Rails?

I also tried checking if the input is an array in a before_validation callback, and added a `puts admin_emails.present?`, but it returned `false`, as if it never saw the String input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use postgresql check constraint valid the email column format.
or in your apps.
for exp :

```
digoal=# create domain email as text constraint ck check (value ~ '^.+@.+\..+$');
CREATE DOMAIN
digoal=# select 'digoal'::email;
ERROR:  value for domain email violates check constraint "ck"
digoal=# select 'digoal@1'::email;
ERROR:  value for domain email violates check constraint "ck"
digoal=# select 'digoal@126.com'::email;
     email      
----------------
 digoal@126.com
(1 row)
```

but it cann't used in array type email[].

so use check.

```
digoal=# create or replace function ck_email(i_email text[]) returns boolean as $$
declare
  v text;
begin
  foreach v in array i_email loop
    if substring(v from '.+@.+\..+') is not null then
      continue;
    else
      return false;
    end if;
  end loop; 
  return true;
end;
$$ language plpgsql strict;
CREATE FUNCTION

digoal=# create table t_email(id int, email text[] check (ck_email(email)));
CREATE TABLE
digoal=# insert into t_email values (1, array['digoal@126.com','a@e']::text[]);
ERROR:  new row for relation "t_email" violates check constraint "t_email_email_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, {digoal@126.com,a@e}).
digoal=# insert into t_email values (1, array['digoal@126.com','a@e.com']::text[]);
INSERT 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So after spending many hours trying to figure out if I was doing something wrong, I went with my gut feeling that this is a bug in Rails, and I opened an issue in the Rails GitHub repo: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14716

It hasn't been dismissed, and has been tagged with a few labels, which to me means that the Rails team has acknowledged the bug.